# R - Flexdashboard :Column / Row Layout within Storyboard Frame

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

Is it possible to have a row/column layout within a frame of a storyboard?
More specifically can you have multiple charts in row and/or column layout within a storyboard frame?
If this is possible how would it be accomplished?

Below is what I've scripted so far:

```
ABOUT {data-icon="fa-info-circle"}
=========================================


Executive Summary {data-icon="fa-sticky-note"}
=============================================   


SALES {.storyboard data-icon="fa-chart-bar"}
============================================

### Frame 1




### Frame 2



### Frame 3
```

[image]

What I would like to do now is add a column layout to each frame.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Aaron